# how to compare and merge two xml files in unix

Tags: xml, performance, unix

I have two simple XML files, and looking for a easy way to compare and merge.

**file 1**: will have a structure like this

```
<lab><id>101</id><name>AAA</name></lab>
<lab><id>102</id><name>AAC</name></lab>
<lab><id>105</id><name>AAB</name></lab>
<lab><id>104</id><name>CCC</name></lab>
```

**file 2**: will have a structure like this

```
<drugs><id>101</id><test>bun</test><results>20.45</results></drugs>
<drugs><id>101</id><test>wbc</test><results>20.45</results></drugs>
<drugs><id>101</id><test>rbc</test><results>20.45</results></drugs>
<drugs><id>103</id><test>bun</test><results>20.45</results></drugs>
<drugs><id>103</id><test>crea</test><results>20.45</results></drugs>
<drugs><id>103</id><test>rdw</test><results>20.45</results></drugs>
```

and i would like an output file looking like this

```
<lab><id>101</id><name>AAA</name></lab>
<drugs><id>101</id><test>bun</test><results>20.45</results></drugs>
<drugs><id>101</id><test>wbc</test><results>20.45</results></drugs>
<drugs><id>101</id><test>rbc</test><results>20.45</results></drugs>
```

Actually, I am using as `id` to compare:

```
while read line
do
          for i in `echo $line | sed -e 's%.*<id>\(.*\)</id>.*%\1%p'`
          do
          if grep -q "$i" file2.xml  ; then
            echo $line >> file3.xml
            grep -i "$i" file2.xml  >> file3.xml
            sed -i "/$i/d" file2.xml
    fi
    break
    done
done < file1.xml
```

I works but it is slow when the number of lines are huge. I need a better way to do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you want to print all those lines whose `<id>` is in both files, this `awk` script makes it:

```
awk -v FS="<id>|</id>" 'FNR==NR {a[$2]=$0; next} ($2 in a) {if (f!=$2) {f=$2; print a[$2]} if (f==$2) {print}}' f1 f2
```

For your sample input it returns:

```
<lab><id>101</id><name>AAA</name></lab>
<drugs><id>101</id><test>bun</test><results>20.45</results></drugs>
<drugs><id>101</id><test>wbc</test><results>20.45</results></drugs>
<drugs><id>101</id><test>rbc</test><results>20.45</results></drugs>
```

#### Explanation

- `-v FS="<id>|</id>"` set the field separator to either `<id>` or `</id>`. This way, we can locate the `id` easily.
- `FNR==NR {a[$2]=$0; next}` while reading the first file (`f1`), store all the lines in an array `a[]`, whose index is the `<id>` value.
- `($2 in a) {if (f!=$2) {f=$2; print a[$2]} if (f==$2) {print}}` while reading the second file (`f2`), print either the corresponding line from file1 or the lines from file2, just if they share the `id`.

Answer (score 1):

To manipulate XML from the command line you can use [XMLStarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/doc/UG/xmlstarlet-ug.html) which allows you to query the document through XPath queries, which is resilient to XML output format (i.e. it will still work when pretty-printed).

The command you'd want to use is the [`xml sel`](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/doc/UG/xmlstarlet-ug.html#idm47077139652416), like:

```
xml sel -t -v "/lab/id" -v "/drugs/id" file1.xml file2.xml
```

I am not the power-user I used to be on that nice little tool but it's worth pointing at.